# PHP/SSH regex script/command to delete identical malware code from many files

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, security

I have a virus that has infected thousands of files on one of my client's server.

Fortunately, I have dealt with a lot of other malware on this guy's server and this one looks easy to do simple regex on (he put all his websites on the same account :( but I'm working with him to resolve that).

Basically though, unlike most malware I have seen where it injects php BEFORE the closing ?> of the GOOD code (making it very hard to determine whats good code/bad code), this current malware ALWAYS adds a new `<?php ... malware ... ?>`.

So basically, say there's good code here:

```
<?php
require('./wp-blog-header.php'); 
?>
```

Instead of adding some kind of base64_decode eval immediately after the require statement but before the ?> (which can make removal difficult when the page happens to end in a conditional/complex statement), this will always add the following code with a NEW `<?php ... ?>` like so:

```
<?php
require('./wp-blog-header.php'); 
?><?php ... malware ...?>
```

I don't want to put any malicious code up here but, this is how the malicious code always starts:

```
<?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset($eva1fYlbakBcVSir)) {$eva1fYlbakBcVSir = "tons and tons of characters";$eva1tYlbakBcVSir = "\x6335\1443\3x6f\1534\x70\170\x65";$SNIPSNIPSNIPSNIP;} ?>
```

I'd like to search every file for `<?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset` and if it's the last PHP statement on the page, then delete everything within the

Comment: I dealt with one of these recently. Copy it all to your development machine, and load it into a decent IDE (e.g. Eclipse, Netbeans). Then do a project-wide search and replace.

Comment: i would just restore from backup - you do have back-ups don't you?

Comment: I have tons of backups, but this isnt me :) hes in the middle of a large product launch though... the site cant be down for more than a few moments. i have also fixed the title. @halfer... he has 40gb of shit on his server, tons of videos or i woulda done that already. i want to do this through SSH if i can or a php script

Comment: Search and replace should do the trick. You can do a sitewide search in something like notepad++

Comment: edit one file at at time, sounds very profitable.

Comment: do you have anything useful to add or just more dumb comments? thats 2 in a row

Comment: Download the site to your machine anyway, skipping large files. Wordpress tends to put media files in one location anyway - find out what those location(s) are for you, and don't copy those things from the server.

Comment: @Tallboy - be nice to people. You're a sitting duck for downvotes otherwise `:(`.

Comment: I was referring to Dagon, who hasn't added anything useful except dumb comments. You're helping a lot mang :)

Comment: its over 40 sites in the same cpanel account.. some of them are wordpress, most of them arent. A lot others are special plugins or scripts with videos mixed it, can't selectively do anything like that

Comment: (Anyway, it is best practice to edit a site on a dev machine - after all, with any system, you should test locally before deploying).

Comment: it looks like this malware is on one line, is this correct? If so, `sed` is your friend. `sed -e "s/<?php @error_reportin.*?>//g" --in-place=_cleaned *` this will remove the given pattern from all files (`*`) and store original files with the extension `_cleaned`. But *please* make a backup first!! and read `man sed` for your particular system.

Comment: Someone in the middle of a large project launch should have backups, and not have 40 sites in the same cPanel account.

Comment: Lol I know brad, it's a giant mess. I made all the same recommendations... for now though there is the urgent task of removal at hand

Comment: --in-place doesnt seem to work

Comment: You're not rebuilding/replacing the server? That sounds... brave...

Comment: I am. I said a few time's he's mid-launch. I'm slowly migrating all his other stuff to other cpanel accounts fresh, new ftps, sql passwords, etc. even after i move it though i still have thousands of files to clean up, which i'm not going to be doing by hand. if theres a problem i would just restore from a backup (that i have now configured)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how you clean the entire project with pure php.

> In no respect shall I incur any liability for any damages, including,
>   but limited to, direct, indirect, special, or consequential damages
>   arising out of, resulting from, or any way connected to the use of the
>   code provided, whether or not based upon warranty, contract, tort, or
>   otherwise; whether or not injury was sustained by persons or property
>   or otherwise; and whether or not loss was sustained from, or arose out
>   of, the results of, the use if this code. ;p

```
<?php 
//Enter it as it is and escape any single quotes
$find='<?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset($eva1fYlbakBcVSir)) {$eva1fYlbakBcVSir =\'\';?>';

echo findString('./',$find);

function findString($path,$find){
    $return='';
    ob_start();
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if(is_dir($path.'/'.$file)){
                    $sub=findString($path.'/'.$file,$find);
                    if(isset($sub)){
                        echo $sub.PHP_EOL;
                    }
                }else{
                    $ext=substr(strtolower($file),-3);
                    if($ext=='php'){
                        $filesource=file_get_contents($path.'/'.$file);
                        $pos = strpos($filesource, $find);
                        if ($pos === false) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                        //The cleaning bit
                        echo "The string '".htmlentities($find)."' was found in the file '$path/$file and exists at position $pos and has been removed from the source file.<br />";
                        $clean_source = str_replace($find,'',$filesource);
                        file_put_contents($path.'/'.$file,$clean_source);
                        }
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $return;
}
?>
```

Good Luck.

### UPDATE (With Regex):

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$find='<\?php @error_reporting\(0\); if \(!isset\((.*?)\?>';

echo findString('./',$find);

function findString($path,$find){
    $return='';
    ob_start();
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if(is_dir($path.'/'.$file)){
                    $sub=findString($path.'/'.$file,$find);
                    if(isset($sub)){
                        echo $sub.PHP_EOL;
                    }
                }else{
                    $ext=substr(strtolower($file),-3);
                    if($ext=='php'){

                        $filesource=file_get_contents($path.'/'.$file);
                        //The cleaning bit
                        echo "The string '".htmlentities($find)."' was found in the file '$path/$file and has been removed from the source file.<br />";
                        $clean_source = preg_replace('#'.$find.'#','',$filesource);
                        // $clean_source = str_replace($find,'',$filesource);
                        file_put_contents($path.'/'.$file,$clean_source);
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $return;
}
?>
```

Comment: No probs, hope you get everything sorted.

Comment: By the way, how would I change it so anything can go in between: `<?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset(` and `?>` .. i think the code changes every time but the beginning and end are always the same

Comment: THanks!!! You're awesome. that is such a huge help. id vote your post 10 times if i could

Answer (score 1):

So far this is the closest (thank you mvds)

`sed -e "s/<?php @error_reporting.*?>//g" --in-place=_cleaned *`

although --in-place=_cleaned is giving the error `sed: illegal option -- -`