# Automatically delete first <?php> tag from php files using python

Tags: python

How to delete the first `<?php>` tag from all `.php` files, for example:

```
<?php $kfefji = jnd637!$%*Uyei85778*(&hdhd) ?><?php> not the second one
^^^^^ delete this ^^^                         ^^^^ not this ^^^
```

I have tried some packages of atom.io like delete-lines but it doesn't work for me because I through this I can delete manually.

Comment: You might consider showing some sample data or code to describe what you're looking to do in more detail.

Comment: I want to delete only 1st php tag from each file by using python:-
<?php $kfefji = jnd637!$%*Uyei85778*(&hdhd) ?><?php>
not the second one.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422503/php-ssh-regex-script-command-to-delete-identical-malware-code-from-many-files

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you were infected by a malware...

Generally, using regular expressions is not a good idea for parsing html/php files, but for this case, it might be enough.

The python code for this would be something in this fashion:

```
text = re.sub(r'<\?php(.+?)\?>', '', text, 1)  # (untested)
```

But using sed as described here would probably be better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422752/57952