# Ubuntu - Find pattern in files for entire directory recursively and replace/remove just the pattern - not the whole line or file

Tags: php, ubuntu, sed

this gives me an error

```
sudo find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.eeduelements.com/jquery.js?ver=1.0.8'></script>//g' {} \;
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown option to 's'

I am open to anything, i just need that pattern removed from every file and cannot seem to get it right.  There are too many to go through manually.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your not escaping the `'`'s

Comment: Is there another route i could go about finding that specific pattern and removing it from a ton of files.

Comment: Could do it in php.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422503/php-ssh-regex-script-command-to-delete-identical-malware-code-from-many-files/10422781#10422781 - bit old..

Comment: I may have to try that.  Looks like that guy needed it to clean up from malware too.  Thanks